# What was Prince Henry Fredrick's personality towards people of other religions like, especially Catholics, and especially those who were Spanish?

Tags: religion, england, spain, royalty

What was [Prince Henry Fredrick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Frederick,_Prince_of_Wales)'s personality towards people of other religions like, especially Catholics, and especially those who were Spanish? I really want to know about his attitude towards the Hapsburg kings of Spain.

Comment: He died at only eighteen - how significant could his youthful enthusiasms have been?